# Asset on iOS mobile app does not match mockup

Tags: ios, user-interface, assets

My artboard on Sketch is 640 x 1136 px, which is 2x. I exported my icons and images at 0.5 times, 1 times, and 1.5 times for 1x, 2x, and 3x respectively.

However, when I implemented them on the app, the size of the icons and images appear to be different from that of the mockup, which is a 640x1136 1:1 scale.

Am I missing something here?

I would like tips and examples of other design folks' design workflow from Sketch to mobile while handling the normal and Retina resolutions.

Thank you very much!

Other things to note:

-Exported using Sketch
-Yes I suffixed them correctly for Xcode

Answer (score 0):

640 x 1136 should be the size of your image for @2x, refer to [this handy guide](http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/ultimate-guide-to-iphone-resolutions) for the different screen sizes.

which device(s) have you been testing on? for @3x it doesnt seem like a 1.5x multiplier so i could see why it maybe not working for that device size, but if its not working on @2x and at @1x device im not sure, are you using the asset manager? maybe make sure all the image buckets are filled correctly

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have seen that and http://www.paintcodeapp.com/news/iphone-6-screens-demystified.

However, I'm actually exporting for icons, not the entire background. The generated mockup for 640x1136px has icons that are different-sized from the actual ones on the app.

Comment: have you looked [at this](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html) for icon sizes?

Comment: I apologise for misleading you. I actually meant in-app icons and images (basically assets for the app). 

I don't have any issues with the AppIcon or LaunchImage.

Thanks again.

Comment: I'm testing on iphone 5s, 6, and simulating the rest. Yes I use the asset manager.